# In AGGrid, certain characters in SelectCellEditor are recognized as Type

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

i had a problem in ag-grid.

```
    this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: "Data Type", field: "dataType", sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true, editable: true, 
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: { values: ['String', 'Array', 'Integer'] }, width: 150},
];
```

I defined the column as above, but specific characters were output as below.

[image]

For some reason, ag-grid's SelectCellEditor recognizes a string as a type?

I checked that the output was normal using agRichSelectCellEditor, but in my project, I have to use agSelectCellEditor at present.

Comment: What you are passing into data?

Comment: i'm passing data by cellEditorParams like this.

cellEditorParams: { values: ['String', 'Array', 'Integer'] }

i just passing string array data.

Comment: Your code seems to be Ok.Even with agSelectEditor.

Comment: I also validated that your code is working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/sstENrSVvVYgnTn6?preview

Comment: @MattNienow i found the defect when using 27.3.0 version. thanks.